# Style formatting

Tags: php, javascript

```
<marquee style = "color: Red; font-size: 24px;">

<?php for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) 

{ 
    echo $symbol[$i]; 

    echo "\t"; 

    echo $chng[$i]; 

    echo "\t\t\t"; 

}?>

</marquee>
```

I need to change the color of text based on the value of *$chng[$i]*. i.e. if $chng[$i] >

0.. green, else red.

Comment: Did you mean to put the marquee in the for too?

Comment: Marquee? Seriously?

Comment: I Thought Marquees went extinct when the .com bubble burst. Apparently a few are hanging around. An alternative is to use javascript @ineedhelp

Comment: `<marquee>` is a non standard tag, that is deprecated by W3 (although I can't reall find a reference to that... anyone?) and will make your document fail to validate. There's a CSS3 proposal for a `marquee` style, although I doubt anyone implements it. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/ . JS and Flash alternatives are what is left (google for it, you'll find tons), but the question is: do you REALLY need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<marquee style = "color: Red; font-size: 24px;">
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) { 

    $color = ($chng[$i] > 0) ? 'green' : 'red';

    echo "<span style='color: $color'>";

    echo $symbol[$i]; 

    echo "\t"; 

    echo $chng[$i]; 

    echo "\t\t\t"; 

    echo "</span>";

} ?>
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<marquee style = "font-size: 24px;">
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) 
{ 
    echo '<span style="color: '.($chng[$i] > 0 ? 'green' : 'red').'>'.$symbol[$i]; 
    echo "\t"; 
    echo $chng[$i].'</span>'; 
    echo "\t\t\t"; 
}?>
</marquee>
```

Change the location of the color styling.  Put it on a span wrapping `$symbol` and `$chng` and set the color styling there.

Answer (score 0):

Aouch... More ugly code please! You could at least set a class to the spans instead of hardcoding the color with inline styles. And marquee... no comment.